# Warning: Illegal string offset on php 7.3

Tags: php, arrays, string, warnings

I switched from php 5.6 to 7.3 and when adding content I started getting errors:

> Warning: Illegal string offset 'provider_discount_summ' in ... on line
>   510

```
if (!is_array($data)){
    if ($meta_box[ 'default' ])
        $data[$meta_box[ 'name' ]]=$meta_box[ 'default' ];
    else
        $data[$meta_box[ 'name' ]]='';
}
```

Line 510 is

```
$data[$meta_box[ 'name' ]]='';
```

**Thanks for the help.**

Comment: `$data` is a string (according to the error message), so `$data['provider_discount_summ']` is illegal. Maybe you want to reset it to an array first (`$data = []`).

Comment: `if (!is_array($data)){` if this is false ($data IS an array) you skip it, and if it is true ($data IS NOT an array) you process it like $data is an array.